# How to declare var in vuejs 3 with Composition API?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Reading some vuejs 3 with Composition API docs I see 2 possible way of vars declaring, like

```
const var_name = ref('')
```

or

```
let var_name = ref('')
```

and looks like var declared with “const” can be modified(say getting data with axios request).
I do not see any errors when I use similar code inb my app.

Are these declarations the same? Which way is preferable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think an article like this is still the best way to go here: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/var-let-and-const-whats-the-difference/

As of what is recommended, usually use `const` and if you need to redefine something else on top of it, use `let`. Of course, non primitive types (like Objects) can be mutated, it being out of the `const` scope redefinition.

TLDR: this is more of a JS vanilla question and have nothing to do with Vue or Composition API in particular.